# Scss url() resolves relative to imported scss files

Tags: angular, sass, primeng

We are currently implementing prime ng into our application. I have referenced the scss files under the style tag in the angular.json. I ve looked into the referenced scss and it also contains multiple scss imports. Like `@import _layout.scss` from different folders. The Problem is that the used assets in these imported scss files `url("../images/special/#{$horizontalMenuBgImageLight}")` are resolved relative to the file they are in instead of relative to the main scss i referenced in the angular.json under the style tag.
So i get a "can't resolve" error for these assets. I could just move the folders to the needed location, but i am wondering if this is the correct solution since the folder structure is setup by prime ng like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that since Angular 10 that my described behavior is the default.
For more context: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/17537